# Access Violation in VS2008, but not in VS2002

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I am facing "Access Violation Error" in visual studio 2008 but same code works fine in VS2002. 
I have verified the project settings both are same. I think there is difference in handling of the pointers in VS2008. I think i am missing something.

Can anyone help?

Sample code given below.

```
schemap = (typ_ty_schema *)((dbs_ty_obj *)obj)->f_schema;
```

after executing this line values are not getting assigned to schemap however i can see values in `((dbs_ty_obj *)obj)->f_schema`

Please help.

Niks

Comment: We don't have enough information to help you. However, when using C++ and especially STL containers, this kind of issue may happen if you mix binaries compiled with VS2002 and 2008.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this has anything to do with pointers being handled different. This is probably just a bug in your code which for some reason (different code generation, memory allocation etc...) was hidden in the code generated by VS2002.